# Rails Mongoid - Store sessions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, session, mongoid

Is there any way to store rails sessions in the database using Mongoid(MongoDB)? I have seen a couple of gems but they are about 1 ~ 2 years old.

I'm not sure whether those gems are necessary (e.g. really complex task) to use sessions with mongo, or is there some 'hack' I can do to make it work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this [mongo_sessions](https://github.com/biilmann/mongo_sessions). Still in active use/development according to the commits.

Answer (score 0):

For [mongo_sessions](https://github.com/biilmann/mongo_sessions) you may need to point your Gemfile to the git repo as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13670747/session-store-does-not-work#answer-13671773). If that still doesn't work, you can try [mongo_session_store-rails3](https://github.com/brianhempel/mongo_session_store).