# session_store does not work

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

I try to store user http sessions in mongodb. 
I've found this nice gem: https://github.com/biilmann/mongo_sessions
and trying to use it. 
I get **undefined method `master' for Mongoid:Module**

than I've changed the old

```
:collection => lambda { Mongoid.master.collection('sessions') }
```

to something that should work and bring **sessions** collection:

```
Mongoid::Sessions.default.collections.find{|i| i.name == 'sessions'}
```

But I'm getting: undefined method `find_one' for Moped::Collection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Gemfile, try using the Github repository for this gem instead of the one hosted on rubygems.org. There was a pull request submitted within the last few weeks that has been merged into master, but not yet published as a gem. It looks like it might address your issue.

```
gem "mongo_sessions", :require => "mongo_sessions/rails_mongo_store", :git => 'git://github.com/biilmann/mongo_sessions'
```

Comment: 16 months later and still not published to the gem... O_o